# angularjs - use directive to change parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I'm trying to change a parent scope property from within a directive.

This is the structure of this section of my project (It may help to understand what's going on):

```
-details
--overview.html
--edit.html
--main.html
-directive
--template.html
--controller.js
```

**directive/controller.js**

```
restrict: 'E'
  scope: {
    mode: '@mode',  
    id: '@id'
  }, 
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: './directive/template.html',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs){
    console.log ("link function scope:", scope);
    console.log ("Parent Scope:", scope.$parent.$parent.current);
  }
```

**directive/template.html:**

```
<div class="Selector">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open-{{id}}"/>
        <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open-{{id}}">
            <i class="zone-details-current-mode icon-mode-{{mode}}"></i>
            <span class="hamburger hamburger-1"></span>
            <span class="hamburger hamburger-2"></span>
            <span class="hamburger hamburger-3"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call the above directive from **details/main.html** like below:

```
<selector mode="{{current.mode}}" id="{{current.ID}}"></selector>
```

my **app.js** router configuration is the following:

```
.config([
  '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app.details', {
      name: 'appDetails',
      url: '/:zoneID',
      views: {
        'appContent': {
          templateUrl: './details/main.html',
          controller: 'mainController'
        }
      }
    }).state('app.details.overview', {
      name: 'appDetailsOverview',
      url: '/overview',
      views: {
        'appContent': {
          templateUrl: './details/main.html',
          controller: 'mainController'
        },
        'zone': {
            templateUrl: './details/overview.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        }
      }
    }).state('app.details.edit', {
      name: 'appDetailsEdit',
      url: '/edit/day/:timerEditDay',
      views: {
        'appContent': {
          templateUrl: './details/main.html',
          controller: 'mainController'
        },
        'zone': {
          templateUrl: './details/edit.html',
          controller: 'mainController'
        }
      }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/myHouse');
  }
]);
```

What this directive should be able to do, is to change the mode when clicked on a specific button. The mode is inside `scope.current`, but, to access `scope.current`, I don't understand why I have to append two `$parent`s.

Also, as a side note, when changing mode, it needs to "refresh" the section with the new mode in place.

Any help with this? how can I use the directive to change the parent scope? Thanks for any help and suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope: {
    mode: '=mode',  // CHANGE THIS TO =
    id: '@id'
}, 
 // remove brackets here 
<selector mode="current.mode" id="{{current.ID}}"></selector>
// in link function
scope.mode = [new mode];
```

About the last point : just use a $scope.$watch in your controller. Or you can go for $on/$emit. Check angular event handling on the net it's pretty easy.

Comment: ok, i changed the @ sign with = for two-way binding, but my real question was: why do I have to add scope.$parent.$parent.current.mode to change the mode? shouldn't it be $parent.current.mode?

Comment: it depends if you had some intermediary levels, like an ng-if would have a layer. By the way you shouldn't do this because with what i posted you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I'm reading about $watch...don't I need it for the $watch expression?

Comment: No the `=` mean two way binding, if you write to `scope.mode`, it will write to `current.mode` since they're bound. you will need : `$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.current.mode;}, function(newValue){//process goes here});`

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot to understand how to achieve something like this

Answer (score 2):

Change mode to `=mode` to enable two way data-binding, `@` is passing value as string.

```
scope: {
    mode: '=mode',  
    id: '@id'
},
```